# GCP Dataflow UDF input

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to remove Datastore Bulk with Dataflow and to use JS UDF to filter entities regarding [doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates#adding-fields). But this code:

```javascript
function func(inJson) {
  var row = JSON.parse(inJson);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var date = row.modifiedAt.split(' ')[0];

  return some code
}
```

causes

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "split" from undefined
```

Input should be A JSON string of the entity and entities should have *modifiedAt* property.

What exactly passes Dataflow to UDF and how could I log it in Dataflow console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that modifiedAt is a property you added, I would expect the JSON in Dataflow to match the Datastore rest api (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity).  Which would mean you probably want `row.properties.modifiedAt` .  You also probably want to pull out the `timestampValue` of the property (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#Value).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this newly [published Google Cloud blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/extend-your-dataflow-template-with-udfs) on how to get started with Dataflow UDFs.

With the [Datastore Bulk Delete](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#datastore-bulk-delete) Dataflow template, the UDF input is the JSON string of the Datastore Entity. As noted by Jim, the properties are nested under `properties` field per this [schema](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity).

With respect to your other question about logging, you can add in your UDF the following print statement whose output will show up in Dataflow console under *Worker Log*s:

```
print(JSON.stringify(row, null, 2))
```

Alternatively, you can view the logs in Cloud Logging using the following log query:

```
log_id("dataflow.googleapis.com/worker")
resource.type="dataflow_step"
```